# Check if multiple variables are true or false in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a function that deals with checkboxes. I'm on a piece right now that I want to check if 3 variables are equal to each other (either true or false; it doesn't matter) and execute a command if that is so. I've tried a few different orientations and just can't get it to work.

```
function dump() {
    var u = document.getElementById("dump").checked;
    var x = document.getElementById("tractor").checked;
    var y = document.getElementById("sweeper").checked;
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('dump');
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('tractor');
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName('sweeper');

    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        /*This is the section*/
        if (u==x && x==y)
            e[i].style.display = "block";
            a[i].style.display = "block";
            b[i].style.display = "block";
        /*End*/
        if (u)
            e[i].style.display = "block";
        else
            e[i].style.display = 'none';
        if (x)
            a[i].style.display = "block";
        else
            a[i].style.display = 'none';
        if (y)
            b[i].style.display = "block";
        else
            b[i].style.display = "none";        
    }
}
```

SOLVED

My real issue was I needed to move that statement to the end of the function. I also added brackets for good measure.

```
function dump() {
    var u = document.getElementById("dump").checked;
    var x = document.getElementById("tractor").checked;
    var y = document.getElementById("sweeper").checked;
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('dump');
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('tractor');
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName('sweeper');

    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        if (u){
            e[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            e[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (x){
            a[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            a[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (y){
            b[i].style.display = "block";
        }
        else{
            b[i].style.display = "none";        
        }
        if (u==x && x==y){
            e[i].style.display = "block";
            a[i].style.display = "block";
            b[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error you getting? can you create a fiddle.

Comment: Multi-line `if`s need to use curly braces `{}`

Comment: Next time you ask a question, please describe the behavior your code produces and the behavior it was intended to produce. "cant get it to work" is vague, making it more difficult for people to figure out what's going on.

Comment: `e[i].style.display = u ? "block" : "none";`

Comment: By "cant get it to work" i mean its all brokey. I'm working on a jsfiddle to better visualize my issue. Basically if that line is working properly, it will switch a few containers to "display: block;". The containers aren't showing therefore, "its brokey".

Comment: Unforntunatly for me. I'm also "having difficulties" with the jsfiddle. Thanks for everyone's 2 cents.

Comment: "I also added brackets for good measure." - they're not brackets, they're braces.  and they're not there for good measure, the code would behave differently without them.

Comment: "I want to check if 3 variables are equal to each other (either true or false; it doesn't matter)" - `if ((u && x && y) || (!u && !x && !y)) ...`

Answer (score 4):

You need braces:

```
if (u==x && x==y) {
    e[i].style.display = "block";
    a[i].style.display = "block";
    b[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Otherwise, the `if` only attaches to the next statement,

```
e[i].style.display = "block";
```

The indentation is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Without curly braces your code will have following behaviour

```
 if(u==x)
   statement //if condition applies to only first statement
   statement //will act as assignments
   statement //
```

Hence you should curly braces here

```
if(ui==x && x==y){
    e[i].style.display = "block";
    a[i].style.display = "block";
    b[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have indenting, not braces:

```
/*This is the section*/
if (u==x && x==y){
    e[i].style.display = "block";
    a[i].style.display = "block";
    b[i].style.display = "block";
}
/*End*/
```

The original code would only guard the "e" statement with the if statement and a & b would always execute.

But whatever this does is going to get possibly changed by the following block of if statements based on the individual values of u, x, and y.